# Fuse Container is not running

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I'm working on apache camel's fuse project .

I'm trying to deploy my application by Fabric8. I have installed all the stuffs required .

I also created a container . i deployed my application via the command

```
fabric8:deploy
```

On the web-based console, after creating a child container (under the root container) i found out that container not running even the start button for this child is disabled so i could'nt run it.

What should i do ?.

Comment: Have you check what the logs says? Look to the fuse.log and whatever other file in the data/logs directory of the container and also the root. The containera are under the instances/<name_of_container>/ folders.